# NppToR Error, cannot retrieve Text

Tags: notepad++, r

I use Notepad++ to write my R-scripts and NppToR passes lines or the entire file to R which serves as a very convenient combination of programs concerning the workflow for R scripting.

Now, NppToR complains that it cannot retrieve the text for unknown reasons:

**"NppToR was able to find Notepad++ but for unknown reason was unable to retrieve text."**

... does anybody have come over this kind of behaviour and found a solution - I am stucked. I tried several combinations of Notepad++ (now running 6.2.2) and NppToR (now running 2.6.2) but nothing changed.

System: Windows7 64 Bit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to close TeamViewer - I guess it captured my hotkey inputs to send them to another computer - although I was not connected.